# convergence of $\int_{0}^{+ \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} - x - 1)^\alpha dx $

Tags: integration

For which value $\alpha$ does the following integral converges: 
$\int_{0}^{+ \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} - x - 1)^\alpha dx $

---

I tried to use: $ \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} - 1 = \frac{x^2 + 2x + 1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} + 1} $

I wanted to simplify it more but that didn't lead to anything.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try using the fact that (x+1)^2=x^2+2x+1 and then substitute for (x+1), this might help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}-x-1=\frac{x^2+2x+2-(x^2+2x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+2}+x+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}+x+1}\sim \frac{1}{2(x+1)}$$
So our integral converges if
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{(2(x+1))^\alpha}$$
 converges, do you know when this integral converges? You can compute the anti derivative to assure yourself.

Comment: By making the substitution: $x+1 = u$
The anti derivative is: $I_{\alpha} =  \int_{0}^{\alpha} \frac{1}{u^{\alpha}} du =  \frac{u^{1 - \alpha}}{1 - \alpha} $. When $\alpha$ approaches 1, $I_{\alpha}$ diverges. 

And $\lim_{\alpha \rightarrow + \infty} I_{\alpha} = 0$  

So, it converges when $ \alpha > 1$. Is it correct? Thank you.

Comment: @Jacob. Yeah that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

$I_a =\int_{0}^{+ \infty} (\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} - x - 1)^a dx
$

Use the standard method of
$a-b
=\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a+b}
$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} -( x + 1)
&=\dfrac{(x^2 + 2x + 2)-(x+1)^2}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} + x + 1}\\
&=\dfrac{(x^2 + 2x + 2)-(x^2+2x+1)}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} + x + 1}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} + x + 1}\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore
$\dfrac1{2(x+1)}
\gt \sqrt{x^2 + 2x + 2} -( x + 1)
\gt \dfrac1{2(x+2)}
$.

Therefore
$I_a$ converges
if and only if
$\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{dx}{(x+1)^a}
$
converges
and this is when
$a > 1$.